# F# tricky recursive algorithm

Tags: list, recursion, f#

I have this code in VBA (looping through the array a() of type double):

```
   bm = 0                                       'tot
   b = 0                                        'prev
   For i = 24 To 0 Step -1
      BP = b                                    'prevprev = prev
      b = bm                                    'prev = tot
      bm = T * b - BP + a(i)                    'tot = a(i) + T * prev - prevprev
   Next
   p = Exp(-xa * xa) * (bm - BP) / 4            '* (tot - prevprev)/4
```

I'm putting this in F#. Clearly I could use an array and mutable variables to recreate the VBA. And maybe this is an example of the right time to use mutable that I've seen hinted at. But why not try to do it the most idiomatic way?

I could write a little recursive function to replicate the loop. But it kind of feels like littering to hang out a little sub-loop that has no meaning on its own as a standalone, named function.

I want to do it with List functions. I have a couple ideas, but I'm not there yet. Anyone get this in a snap??

The two vague ideas I have are: 1. I could make two more lists by chopping off one (and two) elements and adding zero-value element(s). And combine those lists. 2. I'm wondering if a list function like map can take trailing terms in the list as arguments. 3. As a general question, I wonder if this might be a case where an experienced person would say that this problem screams for mutable values (and if so does that dampen my enthusiasm for getting on the functional boat).

To give more intuition for the code: The full function that this is excerpted from is a numerical approximation for the cumulative normal distribution. I haven't looked up the math behind this one. "xa" is the absolute value of the main function argument "x" which is the number of standard deviations from zero. Without working through the proof, I don't think there's much more to say than: it's just a formula. (Oh and maybe I should change the variable names--xa and bm etc are pretty wretched. I did put suggestions as comments.)

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll add to it in a bit. It's hard. I'm still trying to set it up sensibly enough to pose it.

Comment: Maybe also include what `T` and `xa` are and a description of what the thing is supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just standard recursion.  You make your exit condition and your recur condition.

```
let rec calc i prevPrev prev total =
  if i = 0 then  // exit condition; do your final calc
    exp(-xa * xa) * (total - prevPrev) / 4.
  else // recur condition, call again
    let newPrevPrev = prev
    let newPrev = total
    let newTotal = (T * newPrev - newPrevPrev + a i)
    calc (i-1) newPrevPrev newPrev newTotal

calc 24 initPrevPrev initPrev initTotal
```

or shorter...

```
let rec calc i prevPrev prev total =
  if i = 0 then
    exp(-xa * xa) * (total - prevPrev) / 4.
  else 
    calc (i-1) prev total (T * total - prev + a i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my try at pulling the loop out as a recursive function. I'm not thrilled about the housekeeping to have this stand alone, but I think the syntax is neat. Aside from an error in the last line, that is, where the asterisk in (c * a.Tail.Head) gets the red squiggly for float list not matching type float (but I thought .Head necessarily returned float not list):

```
let rec RecurseIt (a: float list) c  =
    match a with
    | []->              0.0
    | head::[]->        a.Head
    | head::tail::[]->  a.Head + (c * a.Tail) + (RecurseIt a.Tail c)                             
    | head::tail->      a.Head + (c * a.Tail.Head) - a.Tail.Tail.Head  + (RecurseIt a.Tail c)
```

Now I'll try list functions. It seems like I'm going to have to iterate by element rather than finding a one-fell-swoop slick approach.

Also I note in this recursive function that all my recursive calls are in tail position I think--except for the last one which will come one line earlier. I wonder if this creates a stack overflow risk (ie, prevents the compiler from treating the recursion as a loop (if that's the right description), or if I'm still safe because the algo will run as a loop plus just one level of recursion).

EDIT:
Here's how I tried to return a list instead of the sum of the list (so that I could use the 3rd to last element and also sum the elements), but I'm way off with this syntax and still hacking away at it:

```
let rec RecurseIt (a: float list) c  =
    match a with
    | []->              []
    | head::[]->        [a.Head]
    | head::tail::[]->  [a.Head + (c * a.Tail)] :: (RecurseIt a.Tail c)                             
    | head::tail->      [a.Head + (c * a.Tail.Head) - a.Tail.Tail.Head]  :: (RecurseIt a.Tail c)
```

Comment: Oh one problem with this approach is that the algorithm uses the sum of 25 terms (using the 25-element array)--which this function returns--but the algorithm also uses the 23rd term of that sum. So I really should return a list of elements that get summed. Which I started to do but had syntax trouble with. I should be able to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my try at a list function. I think the problem felt more complicated than it was due to confusing myself. I just had some nonsense with List.iteri here. Hopefully this is closer to making sense. I hoped some List. function would be neat. Didn't manage. For loop not so idiomatic I think. :

```
for i in 0 .. a.Length - 1 do
    b:: 
        a.Item(i) +
            if i > 0 then
                T * b.Item(i-1) -
                    if i > 1 then
                        b.Item(i-2)
                    else
                        0
            else
                0
```